# Issue with htaccess when deploying next js app to FTP (filezilla)

Tags: javascript, .htaccess, ftp, next.js, filezilla

**EDIT:**
Host had **subdomain**, so I have added `basePath: "/thesubdomain",` and **now** it **works properly**.

I tried to upload the `out` directory from next js app to filezilla that comes out after
`next build && next export`.
However now styles does not load and the nextjs basic router does not work too.

Basically raw html loads to browser.

How my `.htaccess` looks like (maybe that is the issue, dunno):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ index.html [QSA,L
```

I didn't find anything in docs/google.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: @juliomalves I've done it now. Thanks :)

Comment: can you tell me what is the solution , I am having same problem

Comment: @Lokeshthakur The answe I've provided to this post was the solution to the problem :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If **host** has **subdomain** (as in my case), try adding a `basePath: "/thesubdomain"` to your `next.config.js`.
That should solve the problem.

Answer (score -1):

I'll suggest you run next build && next export on your local and then deploy the .next or build folder to FTP